# Can't get FOR loop to work

Tags: python, loops

Below, I've inserted some code that is clearly wrong to all but the most novice of Python users.

Would people be so kind as to suggest some rookie improvements to the code, please? Such as logical variable names, adding comments, etc.

Corrections to the errors in the code will also be appreciated, as per the request in the question.

---

> I'm having a problem with getting the loop below to work. Does anybody have a suggestion as to what's wrong? At the moment I get asked the question, and then the code shows an error.
>
> What should happen is that I am asked a question, and then have 3 chances to answer correctly.

```
a = input("What is the opposite to night?")

for xx in range(0,3)
    if a == Night:
    print("That's right! Well done")
    else:
    print("Sorry, try again")
```

Comment: When asking for help, please copy all details regarding the error you're getting into the question: **exact** error message, ideally copy-pasted, action(s) that lead to the error, etc.

Comment: You should make sure that you're also teaching the next generation of computer scientists [ask] a good question.

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ is an excellent list of questions you should ask yourself before posting a question.

Answer (score 4):

Please see below correction:

```
a = input("What is the opposite to night?")

for x in range(0,3): # must have colons at the end of for statement
    if a.lower() == "night":   # we should accept all cases
      print("That's right! Well done") # indentation required in if statement
    else:
      print("Sorry, try again") # indentation required also
```

Comment: This answer is not correct... not even close. See @Willem-Van-Onsem answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be more valuable to ask what is right:

- The **`input(..)` is only called once** an not in the loop;
- there is **no colon** at the end of the `for` loop;
- you should **use a string** to compare the answer, so `"Night"`;
- the string actually should **compare against `"day"`** since that is the correct answer;
- the answer is better tested **case-insensitive**;
- one should not say `"try again"` if it was the **last chance**;
- it is "opposite **of**" (kudos to @TemporalWolf);
- there is **no `break` if the answer is correct**; and
- the **indentation is wrong**.

So a fix would be:

```
for xx in range(0,3): # colon
    a = input("What is the opposite of night?") # input in the loop
    if a.lower() != "day": # comparing against "day" (string)
        if xx < 2: #only print try again if it is not the last chance
            print("Sorry, try again") #indentation
        else:
            print("Too bad, well goodbye.")
    else:
        print("That's right! Well done") # indentation
        break # break if correct
```

Additional suggestion: you can use `range(3)` instead of `range(0,3)` which is shorter.

Comment: What is the opposite **of** night :) also: `for xx in range(3)` works just fine. And if you aren't adding a fancy extra taunt, `for _ in range(3)` is better, as it is unambiguous that you aren't using the loop variable.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: actually here we are to verify that we are looping for the last time. Nice spotting of the grammar error :).

Comment: I think it's worth noting `range(0,3)` and `range(3)` are equivalent. Also, the of/to *might* be a US/UK thing.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: well there is no problem with the `range(0,3)` and if I understood my English teacher correct, *opposite **to*** means physically opposite, so like left to right (something like "the mountain is opposite to the lake").

Answer (score 1):

```
for _ in range(3): print(["Sorry, try again", "That's right! Well done"]
[input("What is the opposite to night?").lower()=='day'])
```

> Not all answers will be helpful, even if they produce the "right" answer

&

> If you 'borrow' code from StackOverflow, you'll probably get found out.

Answer (score -2):

```
for xx in range(0,3)
```

should be

```
for x in range(0,3):
```

and furthermore can be optimized (albeit very minimally with a small range) by

```
for x in xrange(3)
```

Lastly, Night needs to be wrapped in quotations so:

```
if a == "Night"
```

Comment: `xx` vs `x` is not really relavant

Comment: @cricket_007 true, it adds to readability and I added the colon in that line.

Comment: Sure, but these aren't the only issues :)

Comment: Very true. I may have rushed through that :P